# how to make cmake not silent GNU make

Tags: cmake, makefile, gnu-make

A makefile generated by cmake has following lines:

```
# Command-line flag to silence nested $(MAKE).
$(VERBOSE)MAKESILENT = -s

#Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:
```

So when make executes recipes, it does not print commands it will execute.
But I come across compilation errors when I execute cmake. I need to have a look at the command which leads to the problem.
So how can I set cmake to show the commands that make will execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON`, or `make VERBOSE=1`, or both.